# Jquery UI: range slider. Which slider are moved?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

At this demo page: http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#event-change

The event 'slide' rewrite has two inputs at once:

```
$( "#amount" ).val( "$" + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 0 ) +
            " - $" + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 1 ) );
```

For my purposes I want to know, which of two sliders are moved (min or max). How I can get it?

Comment: _min or max_? Can you elaborate?

Comment: Are you asking about two sliders, each with a single handle, or a single slider with two handles (a "range" slider)?

Comment: Matt Ball, i asking about single slider with two handles.

Comment: undefined, i have slider with two handles (selecting minimum and maximum of range). 'Slide' event called if minimum or maximum was changed. I must know which handle was changed. (sorry for my English)

Comment: The code here http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#range shows you how to target each handle's values. `ui.values[0]` refers to the first handle and `ui.values[1]` the second. However without seeing all your code, I can't help further.

Comment: j08691, yes, i see this example. I want know ui.values[WHICH] was moved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@Nikoole, there is no specific method to find which handle is sliding, but you could try this trick

```
var minSlide = 75, maxSlide = 300;
$("#slider-range").slider({
    range: true,
    min: 0,
    max: 500,
    values: [ 75, 300 ],
    slide: function( event, ui ) {
       if(minSlide != parseInt(ui.values[0], 10)){
          // Do what in minimum handle case
       }
       else if(maxSlide != parseInt(ui.values[1], 10)) {
          // Do what in maximum handle case
       }
    },
    stop: function(event, ui){
        minSlide = parseInt(ui.values[0], 10);
        maxSlide = parseInt(ui.values[1], 10);               
    }
 });
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: Don't forget the radix when using parseInt.

Comment: Kundan Singh Chouhan, a lot of thanks! Do you mean: `else if(**maxSlide** != parseInt(ui.values[1], 10)) {
          // Do what in maximum handle case
       }`

Comment: @Nikoole, thanks for pointing out such issue. I have updated my answer have a look.

Comment: There is `ui.handle` in the events which tells you which one is sliding, although I think your method is still a reasonable answer.

Comment: @Nal, Thanks for sharing this. But i don't think so it will tell what have to done on which handle slide.

Answer (score 12):

Right slider handler is the last child of slider container, so, unlike left handler, right handler has not nextSibling:

```
$('#slider-range').slider({ 
    range: true,
    min: 0, max: 500,
    values: [ 75, 300 ],
    slide: function(event, ui) {
        if (ui.handle.nextSibling) {
            // Moving LEFT slider ...
        } else {
            // Moving RIGHT slider ...
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: beautiful solution! worked perfect for a `return false` condition.. thanks!

Comment: that's fastest solution!

Answer (score 8):

Even I faced the same problem recently. When using a range slider, you need to determine which slider (right or left) was moved. There is *no direct* way to determine that, but however, `ui` object has attributes , `value` and `values` that you can use to determine which slider was moved.
Here is the solution that worked for me :-

```
      $( "#slider-range" ).slider({
      range: true,
      min: 75,
      max: 300,
      values:[75,300],
      slide: function( event, ui ) {
        target_name = ''
        if(ui.values[0] == ui.value) target_name = 'min_price'
        else if(ui.values[1] == ui.value) target_name = 'max_price'
        alert(target_name)
      }
```

Answer (score 4):

The slide event takes two parameters: event and ui. ui contains a handle object. You can access and test the index of the handle like so:

```
$("#slider-range").slider({
    range: true,
    min: 0,
    max: 500,
    values: [ 75, 300 ],
    slide: function( event, ui ) {
        var index = $(ui.handle).index();
        if (index == 1) {
            // do stuff for minimum
        }
        if (index == 2) {
            // do stuff for maximum
        }
    }
});
```

This works for any number of handles in a given slider. But note that the indexes start at 1 not 0.

Comment: finally a great answer !!! I was looking for it for ever. where did you find the index function??

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by setting ID attribute to min and max selectors on create event defined by slider API http://api.jqueryui.com/1.8/slider/#event-create.

```
          create:function(event, ui) 
      {
         var handlers = $('.ui-slider-handle');
         $.each(handlers, function(i, element)
         {
            if(i == 0)
                $(element).attr('id', 'slider-handler-min');
            else
                $(element).attr('id', 'slider-handler-max');
         });
      }
```

...and then back in my `slide` event I simply red ID attribute from `ui.handler` to get which one is moving :)

Comment: I like your solution, but using ID will clash if there is more than one slider on the page. I would suggest adding a class instead. This may also allow a single slider to have a class of max and min, and so avoid having to code differently for single and ranges.